# NameError: undefined in RSpec when trying to test an output that calls a variable located in the method

Tags: ruby, rspec

https://gist.github.com/7wQvRTU2/3c95e82943d2640986fe6bf53a73cb01

Under:

```
describe('#anagram_check')
```

I'm trying to test:

```
 it("returns similar letters if not an anagram") do
    testing = AnagramCheck.new("quick", "quack'")
    expect(testing.anagram_check()).to(eq("Not an Anagram or an Antigram but "
    + (@word1 - antigram).join(',') + " " + "are alike")) 
    end
```

But getting:

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `antigram' for 
   #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AnagramCheck:0x007f97f11980d0>
   # ./spec/anagram_test_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From what I've read it has something to do with scope?

Maybe something involving let?

How do I format this in RSpec correctly so that I can test a method output that returns a variable from within the method?

Comment: Is it `antigram` being defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes should have clarified. Updated post.

Comment: I meant in the spec. You've declared an `antigram` local variable within `antigram_check` but that won't be available moreover than the same class which it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it available across the whole spec, just throw it at the top of the file.

```
RSpec.describe Whatever do
  context 'something' do
    describe 'some function' do
      context 'with new record' do
        let(:mode) { create(:mode) }

        ...

        it 'returns similar letters if not an anagram' do
          ...
```

Then you don't have to keep declaring it. If that's what you're after.